# (DevExpress) Highlight a Row

Tags: winforms, devexpress

i am trying to highlight a row on my gridview.I tried using this approach [RowStyle](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_RowStyletopic) but i think that doesn't suite me as i need to show the column on the Gridview. Lets say i have Id, FirstName and LastName column on my DataTable but only the FirstName and LastName is showed on my grid. I want to highlight all rows which has an ID greater than 50.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are exactly right with using the RowStyle event. Just get the value from your DataSource and check the Id. This should do what you need:

```
private void grdvView_RowStyle(object sender, DevExpress.XtraGrid.Views.Grid.RowStyleEventArgs e)
{
  DataRowView row = grdvView.GetRow(e.RowHandle) as DataRowView;

  if (row != null &&
     !Convert.IsDBNull(row["ID"]) &&
      Convert.ToInt32(row["ID"]) > 50)
  {
     e.Appearance.BackColor = Color.BlueViolet;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks buddy. What i did as an alternative was to hide the column :D

Comment: Your welcome. Always make sure that the gridView is just the View of your underlying DataSource. So if you need to work with your data you should use the DataSource.